# Is there a way to create a jar file in a maven project only with the enums or interfaces?

Tags: java, maven, jar, enums

I have a project with a standard pom and jar packaging.
The standard -.jar is a desirable artifact of this project.

Additionally to the standard jar with all the classes of this project i need to create an additional jar only with the enums declared on it.

If i am abble to generate this jar in a maven standard with a different artifactId would be a plus.

This question here [Create several jar files from single project using maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806999/create-several-jar-files-from-single-project-using-maven) would be a good starting point but there is no answer

Any ideas?

Comment: Just find out this
http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/#.VnsFVXyrSis that with some naming conventions could help.
Testing options now

Comment: Multiple project builds are a thing in Maven.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to have a Maven multi-module build.

Typically, this consists of a single parent module plus multiple child modules.

The packaging of the parent module should be "pom" and it will only act as a container of the child modules.

The parent's pom.xml will look something like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>your groupID</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Name</name>
    <modules>
        <module>submodule1</module>
        <module>submodule2</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Each module should be the name of a subdirectory.  These subdirectories will contain their own `pom.xml` files.

Note that the `groupId`, `artifactId`, and `version` will be used later, so they should be something meaningful.

Your two child modules should look like normal `jar` packaging POM files with a few exceptions:

1. Each module should have a `<parent>` element points to the `<groupId>`, `<artifactId>`, and `<version>` of the parent module.  While this section isn't strictly necessary, it **does** let you define common dependencies in the parent module.
2. The regular module will have the enum module as a dependency.  You declare this just like any other dependency, but be aware that Maven compiles modules **in order**, so the enum module should be in the parent pom first.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you break your classes into two maven artifacts: one with the Enums and Interfaces as a dependency of the other which has your implementations.  Since each has it's own POM you'll get two jars out of a build.

Answer (score 0):

I end up using profiles to manage the solution solution. One managing the maven-jar-plugin plugin and other for the maven-source-plugin.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>enum</id>
    <build>
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <classifier>enum</classifier>
               <includes>

                  <include>**/*Enum**</include>
                  <!-- or any other way to math my artifacts -->
                </includes>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>enum-sources</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mavenSourcePluginVersion}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>attach-sources</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
              <configuration>
                <classifier>enum-sources</classifier>
                   <includes>
                      <include>**/*Enum**</include>
                      <!-- or any other way to math my artifacts -->
                    </includes>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

In this way i can use

```
mvn install -Penum
```

to generate the jars with only the enums
and

```
mvn install -Penum-sources
```

to generate the jars with the sources.

to include this dependencies in other maven projects all you need is to specify the profile with classifier as in

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>{artifactId}</artifactId>
  <version>${version}</version>
  <classifier>enum</classifier>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>{artifactId}</artifactId>
  <version>${version}</version>
  <classifier>enum-sources</classifier>
</dependency>
```